# Почему при нажатии кнопки не выходит текст , который я вписал в input

Tags: php, html

Почему при нажатии кнопки не выходит текст , который я вписал в input .
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="unique.php">
    <label >login</label>
    <input name='input_login' id="input_login" type="text">
    <p id="error_login">Данный логин уже занят</p>
    <label>email</label>

    <input id="input_email" type="text">
    <p id="error_email">Данный email уже занят</p>
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script> 
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Php

```
 <?php

$login = $_POST['input_login'];

echo $login;
```

Comment: `<form action="unique.php" method="post">`

Comment: У вас такая форма по умолчанию отправляет $_GET, а не $_POST

Answer (score 1):

Если не указывать метод, форма отправляется GET-запросом. Чтобы отправлять POST запросы, в строку

```
<form action="unique.php">
```

добавим method="POST", получится

```
<form action="unique.php" method="POST">
```